# MVC 5 custom logic authorization using windows authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, authorization, rbac, abac

I have a MVC 5 project with Windows authentication.

I am using the default WindowsTokenRoleProvider  as my role provider and it works for the following situation:

```
[CustomAuthorization(Roles = "DOMAIN\example_group")]
public ActionResult Action()...
```

It works great.
The problem starts when I want to use custom role, for example: "Approver". In order to check who is a real approver, I have to query a special table and use custom logic to decide if the current person is an Approver.

In order to do this, I have overridden the `AuthorizeCore` of `CustomAuthorize`, and wrote something like this:

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    if(CheckIfCurrentUserIsAnApprover()){
        return true;
    }
    ...........
}
```

But what will happen when I will add another role, lets say `Managers`, I will have to add:

```
if(CheckIfCurrentUserIsManager()){
        return true;
}
```

How can I make it more generic?

Comment: Could you not just use the role as an argument? So..CheckIfCurrentUserIsA("Approver"); or CheckIfCurrentUserIsA("Manager"); and handle this in the method?

Comment: Unfortunatly no. I need to check several condition, for example: does this user has X records with certain flag etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is a clear cut case for attribute based access control (ABAC).

ABAC extends role based access control with attributes so that you can make decisions based on things like a user's approval limit.

In ABAC, you get to write access control policies such as:

- a user with the role==approver can do the action==view on an object of type==transaction if the user.location==object.location.

The language used to write the policies is XACML (extensible access control markup language).

XACML also defines an architecture with the notion of:

- policy enforcement point: the  interceptor in front of your app
- policy decision point: the engine that reaches decisions

You can read more here: http://developers.axiomatics.com/blog/index/entry/xacml-reference-architecture.html. Axiomatics provides a .net engine and a .net pep.